# PHP for loop not appending all strings

Tags: php, html, string, for-loop, append

I am trying to create a PHP function that generates code for Bootstrap 4 form input drop-down. The data is read from a JSON file and using a for loop each line is getting appended to a string variable. I am using '$json_obj = json_decode('file_name.json', true)' to read the data.

Sample JSON input :::

```
[{
    "name": "Peter",
    "user_name": "ughcsa484"
},
{
    "name": "Sam",
    "user_name": "ss648"
},
{
    "name": "John",
    "user_name": "7eddc4c"
},
{
    "name": "Helen",
    "user_name": "thec7841"
}]
```

Code :::

```
    $output = '<select class="custom-select" id="'.$element.'">';
    $output = $output . '<option selected value="999">Select...</option>';
    for($i=0;$i<sizeof($json_obj);$i++)
    {
        echo($i.' - '.$json_obj[$i]["name"]);
        $output = $output . '<option value="'.$i.'">'.$json_obj[$i]["name"].'</option>';
    }
    $output = $output . '</select>';
```

The string append inside the for loop is only working once. But the for loop is working fine and 'echo' function inside the for loop is also printing all lines.

Print out from 'echo' function inside for loop :::

```
0 - Peter
1 - Sam
2 - John
3 - Helen
```

Option available in the drop-down :::

```
Select...
Peter
```

Note ::: The generated HTML code is saved as a string value in PHP variable $output. As this is a function, the string is returned back and printed out in the main file with 'echo'.

HTML code generated :::

```
<select class="custom-select" id="element">
    <option selected value="999">Select...</option>
    <option value="0">Peter</option>
</select>
```

Required HTML code :::

```
<select class="custom-select" id="element">
    <option selected value="999">Select...</option>
    <option value="0">Peter</option>
    <option value="1">Sam</option>
    <option value="2">John</option>
    <option value="3">Helen</option>
</select>
```

Comment: [Your code is fine](https://3v4l.org/10MD4)

Comment: Can you dump the `$json_obj` variable?

Comment: Aside: you will want a `name` attribute on that select.

Comment: No JS/scripts interfering with your options?  Are you further post-processing the `$output` variable?

Comment: @Progrock string value saved in $output is returned back to the main file and printed out using 'echo' - I have also added a sample JSON data above

Comment: Your sample looks fine: https://3v4l.org/m95Vq do check your html output.  Disable styles.

Comment: no issues in html print out. it is working fine when using direct 'echo' print out inside the PHP function or when separately returning each line to HTML file instead of saving to variable $output. something is wrong in the appending part. inside for loop expect for the first iteration other lines are not getting appended in the variable.

Comment: But as we've demonstrated your code works for us.  The code you have given can not be the whole story.